# Configuring either threading or multiprocessing to run multiple scripts python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I trying to run multiple scripts, I have one master script which I just replace the name with and run.

The threading method i'm trying looks like this

```
from threading import Thread
import sys

sys.path.append('/python/loanrates/master')

names =  ['BTS', 'ETH', 'CLAM']#, 'DOGE', 'FCT', 'MAID', 'STR', 'XMR', 'XRP' ]
threads = []
for name in names: 
    sys.path.append('/python/loanrates/'+name)

import Master

for name in names:
    T = Thread(target=Master.main(name))
    print T
    threads.append(T)

for thread_ in threads:
    thread_.start()

for thread_ in threads:
    thread_.join()
```

But this only starts the first script, ie the first name in names 'BTS'

Using multiprocessing seems a lot simpler but this time it doesn't recognize Pool

```
import multiprocessing 
import Master

pool = Pool(processes= 2)

names =  ['BTS', 'ETH']#, 'CLAM', 'DOGE', 'FCT', 'MAID', 'STR', 'XMR', 'XRP' ]

pool.map(Master.main(), names)
```

Which would you recommend and what do I need to change the code to for it to work ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to send a function and it's arguments to the thread, not actually call it in your context.

So change this:

```
T = Thread(target=Master.main(name)) # actually calls Master.main(args)
```

To this:

```
# send Master.main and arguemnts to the thread
T = Thread(target=Master.main, args=(name,))
```

Same goes for `Pool.map`:

Change this:

```
pool.map(Master.main(), names)
```

To this:

```
pool.map(Master.main, names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the Pool from the multiprocessing,

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import Master

pool = mp.Pool(processes= 2)

names =  ['BTS', 'ETH']#, 'CLAM', 'DOGE', 'FCT', 'MAID', 'STR', 'XMR', 'XRP' ]

pool.map(Master.main, names)
```

or load only that class in particular

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import Master

pool = Pool(processes= 2)

names =  ['BTS', 'ETH']#, 'CLAM', 'DOGE', 'FCT', 'MAID', 'STR', 'XMR', 'XRP' ]

pool.map(Master.main, names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have go give the argument for `Master.main()` by the thread constructor parameter `args`.

So creating thread instances should be:

```
for name in names:
    T = Thread(target=Master.main, args=(name,))
    print T
    threads.append(T)
```

If you use `Thread(target=Master.main(name)`, `Master.main()` will be called at this point and the return value will be used as target value.